# How to show the derivative function is bounded which has polynomial growth and $\alpha$-dissipativity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials

We have $f:%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}\longrightarrow%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}$ is $C^{2}\left(
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n};%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}\right)$ and satisfies $\alpha$-dissipativity i.e. there exists $\alpha\in%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion$
such that

$<f(x)-f(y),x-y>$ $ \leq\alpha| x-y|^{2}
$

In addition there exist $h\geq0,$ $C_{1}>0$ such that for $j=0,1,2$

$|D^{j}f(x)|\leq C_{1}(  1+|x|^{h})$

How to prove that $Df(x)$ is bounded i.e. there exists $C_{2}\geq0$ s.t
$\left\vert Df(x)\right\vert \leq C_{2}$